# How can I run my WCF Service Library "in process"

Tags: c#, .net, rest, web-services, wcf

I have a WCF CRUD REST API up and running in a Windows Service.  All is well.

I'd like to offer the user the ability to run that inprocess as well; so, instead of running a service (which would require admin) I'd like to have a static library version as well.

With .NET (C#) how would I go about this?  Right now I have:

```
ServiceLib (interesting code)
ConsoleHost
GUI
```

I'd like the GUI to selectively be able to run the ServiceLib code as a full-fledged Windows Service -OR- just as in-process code.  The service way already works, which I assume is harder.

Comment: I should be more clear - I know how to self-host, and I know how to host in a console, and I know how to host in a service.  What I don't know is how to change from one method to another based on user preference.

If the user wants to run it in a Service, I want to run it in a service.  If the user wants to run its as a plain app, I want to do that.  I don't know how to VARY this binding at runtime.

Comment: I see now. Thanks for clarifying!

Answer (score 0):

If you run it now in a Windows service it's already self-hosting, I assume? If GUI app will be the only one using the service in the "in process" mode you can split your "WCF CRUD REST API" ServiceLib into two - one implementing CRUD part and second implementing WCF REST API on top of it. In GUI you'll need only the CRUD part, so no need to bother with self-hosting of REST API in the same (and only) application that's going to call it.

Running a GUI app as a Windows service is usually a pretty bad idea anyway from the sysadmin's point of view. I often run console apps that can be either WCF hosting Windows services or just WCF hosts, but their only GUI is ablility to react to Ctrl-C.